# SocialEngine: Username in URL of New Pages

Tags: php, url, socialengine

In Social Engine,

How can I make it so New Pages I make for users can have their username in the URL.

For example:

I created a page called "Interests"

Rather than http://example.com/pages/interests

I would like http://example.com/pages/interests/(username)

Would be grateful for any help!

Many Thanks,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Post the username in your url, on the interests page just strip your url to the last thin (username).

This what i use

```
$urlprotocol = 'http'; if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$urlprotocol .= "s";} $urlprotocol .= "://";
$urldomain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$urluri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlvars = basename($urluri);
$urlpath = str_replace($urlvars,"",$urluri);

$urlfull = $urlprotocol . $urldomain . $urlpath . $urlvars;
$find = array("detail.php?=");
$replace = array(" ");
$arr = $urlvars;
$currentItem = trim(str_replace($find,$replace,$arr));
```

So my currentItem is now a ID like 9.

So i have a where statement like

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gamemodes WHERE ID=$currentItem");
```

So my result will be now 9. if i put like 54 in mu url my result = 54.
So just think how i can change it like `WHERE`username`=$username`
Just play with this if you need further help contact me ;)